# HTML Assigning the main element to an id

Tags: html, css

The instructions say to assign the main element to an id named hero (which I made in my css file) and I've tried googling for help and I honestly just cannot get my head around how to do this. I tried doing div class="hero" and it didn't work, and my textbook doesn't seem to have an example of this. Thanks for any help.

here is the id im trying to use if it helps,

```
#hero {
height: 300px;
color: #f5f5dc;
background-image: url(heroroad.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: The attribute is `id` and I'm surprised your textbook doesn't have an example of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting confused between classes and id's.

In CSS, the hash symbol means your selector is looking for an element with an id matching that name. So to match an element with an id of 'hero', your HTML would have to look something like:

```
<div id="hero"></div>
```

If you wanted your CSS to match against a class of 'hero', then your CSS selector would look like

```
.hero {
    //your styling
}
```

and your HTML would look like

```
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use class, your css selector will be

```
.hero{
     //style
}
```

but you css selector is #, which is id selector, remember that id selector is # and class selector is .

Answer (score 0):

if you are using id, you can use # in css 
`<div id="hero">` 
`This is id` 
`</div>`

```
#hero{
color: red;
}
```

if you are using class, you can use dot(.) in css 
    `<div class="hero">`
       `This is class` 
    `</div>`

```
.hero{
   color: blue;
 }
```